# Graphing Perfmon Data from SQL in Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I am capturing Performance data from perfmon for some of our Mailbox Servers into SQL. Everything with that is going fine. I can query the data etc.

The SQL table schema is this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Perfmon_MBX]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Server] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ObjectName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [CounterName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [InstanceName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Value] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
    [DateTime] [datetime] NULL
)
```

This is a typical query I am running to pull back data:

```
SELECT
Server,
ObjectName,
CounterName,
InstanceName,
Value,
DateTime
FROM Perfmon_MBX
WHERE ObjectName = 'logicaldisk'
AND CounterName = 'avg. disk sec/read'
AND InstanceName LIKE 'd:\databasefolder\dag1%'
AND Server = 'mailboxserver.domain.com'
AND DateTime > '2012-10-04 09:00:00'
AND DateTime < '2012-10-04 09:20:00'
ORDER BY InstanceName, DateTime
```

The data comes out like in this .csv file I've uploaded here:

http://ge.tt/1M7utuO/v/0?c

The problem I am having, is that each database (in the InstanceName column) needs to have a different series or line on the graph.

I can't see an easy way to do this without manually adding all of the 10 series, which is a bit of waste of time, and this example is a cut down/simple one compared to reality.

Can anyone help me graph this data more easily using Excel?

Do I need to adjust my SQL query somehow, or is there an easy to do this in Excel that I am just totally missing?

If you need any more info please ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did this using a Pivot Table in Excel, in case anyone else wants to know how to do this!